# scrape site with javascript using selenium execute

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a site with javascript. The script is enabled after the user selects a state and then inputs any text in the search field. I used selenium to imitate that and it works fine. 
I thought I could then parse the browser and have the data from the div tag scraped since it was now in the source code, but it did not work. 
I believe I should be using selenium's execute function instead. 
Here is what I have so far:

```html
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

url = "http://findrealtors.org/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
select = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#selst').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#selst > option:nth-child(2)').click()


name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sbmreq')
name.send_keys('a')
form = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.uk-vertical-align.uk-text-center.uk-height-1-1 > div > form > div:nth-child(4) > a').click()


moreinfo = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(moreinfo, "html.parser")   
for next in soup.findAll('div',{"class":"tt-dataset tt-dataset-typeahead"}):
 print(next)
 try:
  for agents in next.find('div',{"class":"tt-suggestion tt-selectable"}):
   print(agents)
 except:
  print("not found")
```

Comment: Print(soup.pretiffy()) and chek whether you are getting the data or not

Comment: Ok I will try that, when I print the soup it does not have the tt-suggestion tt-selectable although it does in the source code of the website.

Comment: When I try  print(soup.pretiffy())TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: That means you are not getting html data in the moreinfo

Comment: okay I got it to work by adding import time and then time.sleep(5) but if there is a way to do it with selenium execute that would make it much more fun

Comment: You can use selenium driver.get(url) after the time function also

Comment: So I've put everything in a loop now and it iterates through states selects them and adds a letter in the search field before going to the next state, when it finishes each state it should clear the field using - driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sbmreq').clear() is there somethig wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Use find element by id. See the selenium doc for finding selector by id

Comment: Yes I changed it and it worked. So at this point everything works fine I grab a name and a state (the value of the dropdown) and add them to a list "name",  "state" \n "name", "state" \n now I want to loop through the list and add state to the state dropdown and name to the text box is there a way to break down the list like that?

Comment: I will update my code